# Long line in bash is partially hidden rather than wrapped

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

When I'm working on a server with a newer OS and bash version via SSH, I find that a long input line is partially hidden. I prefer to see a soft-wrapped line. I don't know if there are some options to change this behavior.

For example, when I input a line "`longgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg`"

On the old server (preferred) :

```
[root@VM-OLD ~] longgggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
ggggggggggggg
```

On the new server:

```
<ggggggggggggg
```

I tried different terminal apps and this behavior didn't change.

How can I get the preferred behavior?

UPDATE:

Kamil kindly posted a link to a similar question. I tried the following fixes described in those answers but nothing changed:

1. `bind 'set horizontal-scroll-mode off'`
2. add "`set horizontal-scroll-mode off`" to `~/.inputrc` and `/etc/inputrc`
3. `infocmp $TERM` and there is an entry output
4. `export TERM=xterm`

Besides, I can confirm that the current shell is bash:

```
$ echo "$SHELL"
/bin/bash


$ ls -l /proc/"$$"/exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 12 11:50 /proc/3420430/exe -> /usr/bin/bash
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/525508/108618

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks for the link. I tried the solution in this link but nothing changed.

Comment: Try also `setterm --linewrap on`.

Comment: @harrymc Sadly it doesn't work...

Comment: (1) `echo "$SHELL"` does not really tell you the current shell; it's technically possible (and quite easy) to run any shell with any value of the variable. In Linux `ls -l /proc/"$$"/exe` is better if you want to know the current shell. (2) [This other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196229/108618) states an entry in the terminfo database is not enough. I believe capabilities that move the cursor up have names starting with `cuu`. What is the output of `infocmp "$TERM" | grep cuu`? (for the old value of `$TERM`, what is it anyway?). What is the output of `infocmp xterm | grep cuu`?

Comment: (1) What is the value of the PS1 environment variable and does it contain escape sequences? (2) Perhaps the size of the window assumed by the terminal is not the same as your actual window size. Try this: `shopt checkwinsize` which should be `on`. If it isn't then run `shopt -s checkwinsize`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski  the value of `$TERM` is `xterm-256color`, and the cmd output is `cup=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dH, cuu=\E[%p1%dA, cuu1=\E[A,
        kcbt=\E[Z, kcub1=\EOD, kcud1=\EOB, kcuf1=\EOC, kcuu1=\EOA,`

Comment: @harrymc the value of `$PS1` is `[\u@\h \W]\$`. `shopt checkwinsize` is `on`.

Comment: What do you use to connect to this server? Maybe it's just a setting in your SSH client that causes this.